# Stand alone vs resource extensions in Orchestra (Laravel)

Tags: php, routes, laravel

I am trying to use the [Orchestra platform](http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/orchestra) for the [Laravel framework](http://laravel.com).

I have installed the [Authorize](http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/authorize), [Robotix](http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/robotix), [Melody Theme Manager](http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/melody) and [Cello CMS](http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/cello) extensions for the platform.

I have noticed that the Authorize, Robotix, and Cello CMS extensions all get listed under Resources, whilst the Melody Theme Manager gets listed as a top level item next to Extensions.

What I want is to have the Cello CMS extension accessible via `/orchestra/manages/pages` in the same manner that the Melody Theme Manager is accessible via `/orchestra/manages/melody.themes`.

I have worked out that to add the top menu item I can use something like:

```
// Attach a menu only if user has the authorization to manage Pages
$acl = Orchestra\Acl::make('cello');
$menu = Orchestra::menu();

if ($acl->can('manage-pages')) {
    $menu->add('Cello', 'after:themes')
        ->title('Pages')
        ->link(handles('orchestra::resources/cello'));
}
```

inside of `Event::listen('orchestra.started: backend', function()`

Which adds a working link, the issue of course, is that that still points to `resources/cello` so how can I make it respond to `manages/pages` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cello CMS is by design to use `Orchestra\Resources`, which offer better API for complex CRUD, `manages/pages` are just simple Event listener where you have to add extra code to route it to Controllers. Now at this moment Cello would just handle Page content, but in future we are looking at adding Posts (sort of blog) to it, if we follow the `manages/pages` the API would be hard to maintain (personal preference).

Take this two use case, "Melody Theme Manager" and "Authorize". Melody is using `pages/manages` simply because it would only require theme selection (by a single ACL), while Authorize is using `resources` because it has two type of ACL, "manage-acl" and "manage-role" and two type of resources, which are CRUD for roles, and ACL metric configuration.

I'm considering the possibility to toggle a Resources whether to be listed, but there are pro and con to that approach, which is what you might looking for, but it as to be pointing to the resources URL and not `manages/pages`.